# How do you use the Nginx rewrite module to change the request URI?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I would like to use a single PHP file that uses a request's URI to decide what content to display, while making sure that the URL is user-friendly. The former is easy to achieve, however I am having trouble when I try to implement the latter.

I believe this is exactly the kind of thing the [Nginx Rewrite Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) is made for, but I am having trouble understanding the documentation and I cannot get it to work in the way I was expecting it to. So at this point I am questioning whether my understanding of the module is correct.

Here is what I am trying to achieve, at its most simple:

1. A user goes to `http://www.example.com/another-page`. This is the only URL the user ever sees, it is very nice and neat.
2. Nginx understands this as `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=another-page` and passes the request to `index.php`.
3. `index.php` uses the query's parameter to decide what content to display.
4. Nginx responds to the user with the output of `index.php`.

Here is how I have attempted to do this:

### Nginx.conf

```
server {

    listen                        80;
    listen                        [::]:80;
    server_name                   localhost;

    try_files                     $uri $uri/ =404;
    root                          /path/to/root;

    # Rewrite the URL so that is can be processed by index.php
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1? break;

    # For processesing PHP scripts and serving their output
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    # For serving static files
    location ^~ /static/ {
    root            /path/to/static;
    }
}
```

### index.php

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($uri){

    case '/index.php?page=':
    echo 'Welcome home';
    break;

    case '/index.php?page=another-page':
    echo 'Welcome to another page';
    break;
}

return;
```

**Where have I gone wrong?**

I have tried using the multiple versions of this rewrite rule and `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to see how the rule effects the URI, but it never does how I would like or expect it to. I have tried putting the rule in the `~* \.php$` location context, making slight alterations to the regex, removing and adding `try_files` from contexts, etc. I have done these things always by first checking my regex with [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) and then reloading the Nginx configuration file. In any case, I have either gotten a 500 error, or the URI was left unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is possible with the following config:

```
server {

    listen           80;
    listen           [::]:80;
    server_name      localhost;

    root             /path/to/root;
    index            index.php;

    location / {
        try_files    $uri    $uri/    /index.php?$args;
    }

    # For processesing PHP scripts and serving their output
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    # For serving static files
    location ^~ /static/ {
        root            /path/to/static;
    }
}
```

and a slightly different `index.php`:

```
$uri = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');  //trim GET parameters

switch ($uri){

    case '/':
    echo 'Welcome home';
    break;

    case '/another-page':
    echo 'Welcome to another page';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the attept, but unless I have recreated your code wrong, I do no think this works. `strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')` removes the parameters which would "tell" `switch` which `case` to use, so no code is being run. Also, I do not believe the `/index.php?$args` is working how we would expect it to either. I added `=404` to the end of that `try_files` line, and I get a 404 response every time. Back to the drawing board?

Comment: yes, `strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')` would remove GET parameters. I think you want `/another-page?a=1` and `/another-page?a=2` to be handled with the same `case`, right? that's why GET parameters should be trimmed. `/index.php?$args` would perform internal redirect to `index.php` passing all the GET parameters to it. Just before posting my answer I checked it on my computer, and everything worked perfectly. I just used slightly different approach.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing. This is good, but I must not have explained myself well enough. Essentially, I want every request to be passed to the same file, `index.php`. Let's say the request URI is /broadcat/specificcat/topic. No file or directory "/broadcat/specificcat/topic" exists on the server. I want Nginx to somehow pass the request to /index.php and give `index.php` to have some specific information it can use to determine what to return (information like /broadcat/specificcat/topic). Am I making sense?

Comment: Just give a try my example. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: information about the request resides in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. `index.php` can read it to determine what to do

Comment: Your are right! That is my mistake! This is even better than what I was trying to do. Fantastic! You seem to be a strong purveyor of Nginx; do you feel this configuration conforms well to the way Nginx works? Does it have any security implications that should be considered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90363/discussion-between-jacksonhunt-and-curious).